# Simple EF based table to cache API responses is taking too long

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

I built a simple table using EF that I built to cache some API requests in my ASP.net web application so that I could improve performance for requests making the same REST calls.

This table has 4 rows of test data. When I make a simple SELECT query in SQL Server Management studio with all columns, it takes a good 5-7 seconds to load. If I skip the "CachedData" in the SELECT query it loads instantly. What can I do different to improve my performance. I understand CachedData can be large JSON strings, but I've seen longer strings work quicker in other tables before. Am I missing something?

This is my object/table structure -

```
public class APIDataCache
{
    //Using Composite keys. 

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string TransactID { get; set; } //nvarchar(128), Not Null

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string ResourceID { get; set; } //nvarchar(128), Not Null

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string APIDataLevel { get; set; } //nvarchar(128), Not Null

    public string CachedData { get; set; } //nvarchar(max), Nullable

    public DateTime CachedAtTime { get; set; }//datetime, Not Null
}
```